# Get lower value in multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array A:
[image]

And i have and input text, in this case input value is `level`, for example it is `5`. , The result must be `2`. I want to find **lower level** in array A from input text value. I have no idea how to get in in PHP. Help me,Thanks

Comment: be more specific on what you want.

Comment: I suppose, you want the next lower level after `5`, not the lowest level, right?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest right!

Comment: @ChrysUgwu I want to show lower level based on input text that I typed

Comment: actually, it could be `3` or `4`, not obviously `2`, depending on input array

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest there is no level 3 or 4 in array A

Comment: @NikeYulistiaAngreni, only if your input array is always static and will never get changed. Should it be unchangeable?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest no, it's a dynamic array

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all array of $arrayA

```
foreach($arrayA as $array)
{
   // Check each array has level value 2 or not 
   if ($array['level'] == 2)
   {
       // found value
       echo "found the array";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get array having specific level `2` you can use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) like,

```
$result = array_filter($arrayA, function($k) {
    return $k['level'] == 2;
});
print_r($result);
```

**And** for making it dynamic, to get the lowest level whose `parent_ohp_id` is blank then use,

```
$result = array_filter($arrayA, function($k) {
    return $k['parent_ohp_id'] == "";// this is the root level because it has no parent id
});
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use the `usort()` function to sort the table on the `level` key and then get first element of the array :

```php
<?php

  $array = [
    [
      'john' => 'Snow',
      'level' => 5,
    ],
    [
      'john' => 'Cena',
      'level' => 8,
    ],
    [
      'john' => 'Kennedy',
      'level' => 2,
    ],
    [
      'john' => 'Glenn',
      'level' => 12,
    ],
  ];

  usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['level'] - $b['level'];
  });

  echo current($array)['john']; // This will display "Kennedy".
```

An other way to do that is to use the `foreach` loop and compare the level value with the previous iteration :

```php
  $lowest = $array[0];

  foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($item['level'] < $lowest['level']) {
      $lowest = $item;
    }
  }

  echo $lowest['john']; // This will also display "Kennedy".
```